# Polymer: can not fire jQuery code using onclick action in <paper-button>

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I've stuck with the one specific thing:
when I try to run jQuery code with the standart button - everything works great:

```
<button onclick="$('#dayPicker').val(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'));">Today</button>
```

But it doesn't work when I try to do the same using the polymer paper-button:

```
<paper-button flat onclick="$('#dayPicker').val(moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'));">Today</paper-button>
```

P.S.: I didn't forget to include jQuery. if I put simple js code in onclick, such as "alert("it works!")" - it works.

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `onclick="window.$('#dayPicker')..."` or `onclick="jQuery('#dayPicker')..."`.

Within your `<paper-button onclick="">` handler, the bare identifier `$` is interpreted as `this.$`, which corresponds to the helper used for [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding) in Polymer.

Explicitly using `window.$` avoids this conflict. Using `jQuery` avoids the conflict because `this.jQuery` doesn't exist within the click handler, so it ends up being interpreted as `window.jQuery`.

There are lots of [good articles](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) out there that explain how scoping and identifier resolution work. It's unfortunately not always intuitive or obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the itemized answer! Very helpfull!